# a 'file not found' error message!

Tags: errors

I am a novice on LaTeX. This is what I have and it gave me a
'File Not Found'

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\title{The Report}
\author{Kiem Ta}


\end{document}
```

this gave me a 'file not found'.  any idea?

[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

the document makes no output, add `\maketitle` after `\author` then it will make a PDF file to be found.